# Group of three tiles containing 2 Jokers

Tags: rummikub

Assume, that there is such situation:

Player A creates a group:

> [blue 8] [Joker] [Joker]

and declares, that it is a set of eights.

From this moment these Jokers should be treated as two eights, or is it possible to threat them as blue 9,10 or blue 6,7?

Also, if the declaration of eights is not valid, could these jokers be treated as blue 7,9, despite 8 is not in the middle position?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look up the official rulebook, but if I'm not mistaken, Player A should not only declare it's a group of eights, but also specify the exact colors (e.g. 'red 8' and 'green 8').

This is further supported by e.g. [this page](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/rummikub.html):

> However, a player who has in hand **the** tile which is represented by a joker on the table, the player can substitute the real tile for the joker and then re-use the joker in some combination on the table.

(emphasis mine); there's only one tile it represents.

Since you've tagged it [house-rules](/questions/tagged/house-rules), there is room for some variation on the rules. Some of them are discussed in the linked page; when I was a kid, we played it in a more liberal way than you describe; during your turn, you could use the joker for whatever tile you want (i.e. you don't need to substitute it), as long as the final configuration consisted of valid sets only. That meant e.g. that if you had a blue run of 1, 2, 3, joker, 5, 6, 7, you could basically take out the joker and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I was about to tag it with [rules], but it seems that there is no such tag and I didn't noticed that [house-rules] tag was used. Anyway, declaring even colors seems to be against rules: "In the case of a group of 3, the joker can be replaced by the tile of either of the missing colours."